# react-native - MapView simple example

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create the most simple example for the MapView component.

```
render() {
    return (
      <MapView style={{
        height: 200,
        width: 200
      }}/>
    )
  }
```

I have no errors but the Map does not appear. What I get (on Android) is the following:

[image: screen shot]
I don't see in the documentation any information relative to the initialization of the map.

Any help or clue would be welcome.
Thanks, Paul

Comment: Have you set up a region property and passed in the coordinates?

Comment: Hi Nader, according to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#content Maps is not yet available for Android... Did you succeed on Android?

Comment: Check out the node_modules -> react-native -> Libraries -> Components -> MapView -> MapView.js. It looks like Android is supported, at least in the version I'm on ( 0.13.0 )

Comment: You're a few versions behind.  It may be a bug that has subsequently been fixed.  Perhaps update to 0.17 or 0.18-rc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rechecking, at this time there is no support for MapView on Android. As soon as I am adding `<MapView>` in the code a warning is triggered in the console.

[image]

This is confirmed here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#content

[image]

I checked with other components that are not yet embedded for Android and you will get a `Warning: Native component for "NotAvailableComponent" does not exist.`

Until Facebook releases this missing components the solution seems to pass through a community component like 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gmaps